# Why is the re.findall method return the wrong result in python?

Tags: python, regex

I tried some code like below.

```
re.findall(r'(\d{2}){2}', 'shs111111111')
```

I want to get the result like

```
11111111
```

but the result is

```
['11', '11']
```

---

Edit:

I make some errors at the example, what I really need is to find the all repeated substrings.

Like this:

```
re.findall(r'([actg]{2,}){2,}', 'aaaaaaaccccctttttttttt')
```

I prefer the result is ['aaaaaaa', 'ccccc', 'tttttttttt']

But I got ['aa', 'cc', 'tt']

What's the problem and how can I do?

Comment: Do you want to get all consecutive `1`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need this regex:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'(?:\d{2}){2,}', 'shs111111111');
['11111111']
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on edited question you can use:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'(([actg\d])\2+)', 'aaaaaaaccccctttttttttt');
[('aaaaaaa', 'a'), ('ccccc', 'c'), ('tttttttttt', 't')]
```

And grab captured group #1 from each pair.

Using `finditer`:

```
>>> arr=[]
>>> for match in re.finditer(r'(([actg\d])\2+)', 'aaaaaaaccccctttttttttt') :
...     arr.append( match.groups()[0] )
...
>>> print arr
['aaaaaaa', 'ccccc', 'tttttttttt']
```

Comment: Sorry, I make some mistakes in the question, I have updated it.

Comment: Could you please tell why `re.findall(r'([a-z])\1+', 'aaaaaaaccccctttttttttt')` is not working? Also what does `g` do in `actg` of your answer?

Comment: @heemayl: Actually `actg` was taken from the question. It could be just `act\d` for this example. Also `print re.findall(r'([actg\d])\1+', 'aaaaaaaccccctttttttttt')` will just print first group i.e. `['a', 'c', 't']`.

Comment: However in my `finditer` example we could use `re.finditer(r'([actg\d])\1+', 'aaaaaaaccccctttttttttt')` and then use `arr.append( match.group(0) )`

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall` returns all the groups. So use

```
re.findall(r'(?:\d{2}){2}', 'shs111111111')
```

Just make the group `non capturing`.

Relevant doc excerpt:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

```
(([acgt])\2+)
```

Use this and

```
x="aaaaaaaccccctttttttttt"
print [i[0] for i in re.findall(r'(([acgt])\2+)', 'aaaaaaaccccctttttttttt')]
```

Comment: The result of this is `['1111', '1111']`. This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @LutzHorn `\d{2}{2}` theres only `4` \d` there.I guess OP is has mistyped

Comment: Sorry, I make some mistakes in the question, I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot obtain pure `['aaaaaaa', 'ccccc', 'tttttttttt']` because you need a capture group to check for repetition using the back-reference. Here, you have a regex with named group `letter` that will hold `a`, or `b`, etc. and then the `(?P=letter)+)` back-reference is used to match all the group repetition.

`((?P<letter>[a-zA-Z])(?P=letter)+)`

You can only use this regex with a `finditer` described in @anubhava's post.